# Mac os Recovery keyboard issue

Tags: macos, keyboard, internet-recovery

hi guys I had to replace my HDD to SSD on iMac 21.5 Late 2013
turning on the mac shows startup error which requires to boot into recovery mode
trying to go to recovery mode and install OS but non of the keys has been explained works for me

---

**command** + **R** on apple Wireless Keyboard

---

**Windows** + **R** or **Alt** + **R** on Windows USB Keyboard

any help will be appreciated
thanks

Comment: what is happening instead? did you successfully install the SSD?

Comment: replacing the SSD yes i had to deal with opening the lcd and etc to do so.. now trying to run mac os on SSD but stuck with recovery mode

Comment: well your post includes no question. Do you have macOS already installed already? If not then recovery mode is exactly what you want. Reinstall macOS from there.

Comment: changing the main drive requires clean OS install.. turning on the Mac shows circle error with startup issue so have to boot into recovery which i am Unable to do so